# Windows 10 Blue screen

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I am using windows 10 enterprise.

Sometimes my windows restarts with a blue screen with error code

> memory management, page fault in non page area, critical section, page swapping etc

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try this [driver verifier](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/driver-verifier-tracking-down-a-mis-behaving/f5cb4faf-556b-4b6d-95b3-c48669e4c983) to check which program is causing this problem.

Comment: Check this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/memory-problems/21c3f63f-f570-4522-b2ef-ecc7b7ff6461) to test your memory.

Comment: Can you upload us a dump file, so it can be analyzed with WinDbg?

Comment: Where can i get this dump file ? -DeZoo

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=27122444713530933736

Comment: check your Apacer RAM for errors with memtest86+. it looks like RAM failure.

Comment: But i am still able to use this ram .  magicandre1981

Comment: you also have a Hynix RAM module. mixing different brands can also cause issues. test each RAM module alone with memtest86+

Comment: memtest86 shows 23 errors - magicandre1981

Comment: ok, so the RAM is damaged. remove that RAM module and only use the other one and if you need more RAM buy new RAM